# The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'CommunityToolkit.Maui'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, maui

I'm trying to use FolderPicker following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOzAWGsWKf4) . I did install from nuget package CommunityToolkit.Maui and add it to csproject(I already use it for popup and it worked fine) , but when I try using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Storage like he did it said "Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'CommunityToolkit.Maui' " , I'm using .net6.0 , and in the quick fixe it said install Uno.Ui , should i ? because it is not from community toolkit , I checked the documentation but it didn't help .
here is the code :

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Storage
namespace MauiApp12_tuto;

public partial class Analyse : ContentPage
{
    public Analyse()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public async void folder_pick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var folder = await FolderPicker ;
    }
}
```

Comment: 6.0 is only supported on older versions of the nuget - you probably need to update to 7.0 and use the latest nuget

Comment: I can notice some mistakes, the first line about using, you're missing the `;` and when you are calling FolderPick, it seems that you forgot the `()`, and sometimes you need to see if the library updated and it changed something.

Comment: Like Jason mentioned, you need to use .NET 7.0. The last version of the Community Toolkit that worked with .NET 6.0 is version [2.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Maui/2.0.0#supportedframeworks-body-tab).

Comment: @Jason I guess you are right , I didn't want to update to .net 7.0 I already build a lot in the project . but I guess I have to .